# Detect which shell invoked a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I am building a custom [fetch tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neofetch) to add as a feature for my hobby OS. I wanted to make the script in pure Python.

How can I detect which shell invoked the script? This is a difficult problem because I am calling a script in a script to detect the shell. For example, Python code like `os.getenv("SHELL")` results in `/bin/bash` no matter what.

I also tried these command-line options:

- `getent passwd USERID`  --> Always prints `Bash`
- `echo $0`               --> prints `/bin/sh`
- `readlink /proc/$$/exe` --> Always prints `Readlink`

P.S. :
I am not running a new shell, I am just printing out the name of the shell that invoked this script, It's all for the sake of an aesthetically pleasing look, with some system information.

Comment: Why do you need to determine the shell? Also, you say you are calling a script in a script to detect the shell. Please describe this in more detail - you are calling this Python script inside a shell script, and you want to detect the shell the shell script was called from? Is that correct? Why not determine the shell from the wrapper script, and pass it to Python if needed?

Comment: The `SHELL` variable doesn't tell you which shell is _in use_; it only tells you which shell is the user's configured default; that's the same thing as what the passwd file tells you. And none of those things are relevant to Python: Once you're in a Python interpreter you're no longer in a shell interpreter; `/proc/self`, etc. will refer to the Python interpreter or one of its children. Anyhow -- if you're in Python, why do you care what the parent shell is at all? You can use a shell-agnostic install process _written in Python_ from that point.

Comment: What you _can_ do is inspect the Python interpreter's parent process -- its `ppid` -- but even then there's no guarantee it'll even be a shell in the first place. It's perfectly possible to run a program without using any shell at all.

Comment: @MattDMo I am making a fetch tool I need to view the Shell Name. 
As for how ? I used getoutput("echo $0") or getoutput("echo $SHELL") or getoutput("ps -p $$")

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will try this & for Terminal tool it must run from shell.

Comment: @Hushm, nope! Terminals can be configured to run non-shell programs. For example, you can go into your terminal configuration and tell it to directly execute Python whenever a new tab is created with the "Python" configuration; then, in that copy of Python you can use `subprocess.run(['otherprogram'], shell=False)` and there you are -- an arbitrary program running, no shell at all.

Comment: Anyhow -- stay clear of `getoutput`; every time you use that it's starting a copy of `/bin/sh` as a new/additional shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK, Thnx for that.

Comment: If the **actual** question is "how do I run a script from my Python program and make sure it uses the correct shell for that script?" - did you try specifying a shell application explicitly in the command line that you use with `subprocess`, `os.system` etc.? Otherwise, I can't understand what **problem you hope to solve** by gaining this information.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I need to know which kernel is running that python script not running the script in specific one.

Comment: *"I need to know which kernel is running that python script"* **Why?** Under what circumstance could it possibly make a difference to anything? *"I am making a fetch tool So I need to know the python script shell."* This doesn't answer the question at all. What is a "fetch tool"? Why would the Python code for this need to be different in different shells? (If it is because you will use the shell to run programs, then yes, "running the script in a specific shell" is exactly how to solve the problem; why detect what can easily be controlled?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 
1) The kernel part was wrong I meant Shell.
2) The Fetch tool is like neofetch check it out.

Comment: That doesn't change my questions. Why does it matter, for you as the person who is writing the Python code, what kernel is running the Python script? How does that change the Python code that should be written? Also: please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. Do not edit questions for "updates", and do not put your thanks etc. in questions. Instead, edit questions to clarify them, add missing information, make them more specific etc. so that they are useful as part of a searchable Q&A library.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 
DUDE, I must print which shell for the user, I for example like to know is this user using bash or Zsh or maybe fish, Have you even clicked the link?

Comment: I really do tend to agree with Karl -- if you need to know which shell your user is using, you're doing something terribly wrong. People change shells all the time; installing a program only for shell X or shell Y because that's what they were using at that particular moment when they installed your software is setting someone up to be surprised or disappointed a few minutes later when they have a window with shell Z open instead.

Comment: (Keeping the skepticism to comments because it doesn't change how one actually accomplishes the thing you're asking about, so my answer will remain the best answer I have to that literal question, but... still skeptical on the is-this-actually-a-good-idea? side of things).

Comment: I am not modifying my code based on their shell, I just want to print its name only, not modify it, not changing it, just print the name.

Comment: So the point is simply that your program can *tell me* what shell I used to run it? But... I already know what shell I used to run it, because I was the one who used it to run your program. So why is this useful? The tool that you describe gives system diagnostics, like the distribution of Linux that was used. But essentially any Unix can run any shell; the shell doesn't tell me anything interesting about my computer. Knowing *all installed shells* might be interesting, or knowing the default shell (but you already know how to get *that*: with the `SHELL` environment variable).

Comment: All of that said: if the point is "I want to make a program that tells the user what shell was used, *as the purpose of the program*", then it would be better to *say that*, rather than expect us to infer it from a Wikipedia link.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This might be a bit long so starting from the beginning, fetch tools are used for making personalized experience for the user to show off maybe.

It's kind of tool that people use mainly in Linux ricing, I'm thinking of building a new Linux distro (lfs) this kind of tools are the ones  that I like to make like starfetch etc.

Just because it's not a "practical" tool does not mean it's "bad" tool.

Edit : this is the title of the question exactly.

Comment: Anyway ,Thanks for your help everyone, this is a nice learning experience in phrasing my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, to detect the parent process of your Python interpreter, you can use:

```
os.readlink(f'/proc/{os.getppid()}/exe')
```

If your Python interpreter was directly invoked by a shell (which is not guaranteed!) via the regular fork/exec process (not a direct `exec` replacement-in-place -- again, not guaranteed!), you'll see it returned there.